# How can I count matrix(2d array) elements using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, matrix, count

I want to know how do I count total number of matrix elements? the `count()` function tells me the number of elements of an array, but if i have m[n][n], how do i know how many elements are there? thx
This is the result of `var_dump` : [image]

Comment: add your sample array

Comment: Use `COUNT_RECURSIVE` as second parameter for [`count()`](http://us1.php.net/count)

Comment: @almaDo why not posting an answer ?

Comment: @mb14 posting RTFM link isn't a thing that SO expects as an answer

Comment: maybe, but I'm sure SO will prefer your answer to the accepted one.

Comment: @AlmaDo, I don't think `COUNT_RECURSIVE` will give the intended result. It will give `M+M*N` instead of `M*N`.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo so just do `count($array, 1) - count($array)` (`1` is `COUNT_RECURSIVE`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP COUNT\_RECURSIVE only count non-array values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544173/php-count-recursive-only-count-non-array-values)

Comment: How about `array_sum(array_map("count", $matrix))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

For any dimensional Array count of elements:

Demo :  https://eval.in/87683

```
$food = array('fruits' => array('orange', 'banana', 'apple'),"dsd"=>array('orange', 'banana', 'apple','dsfdsf'),'sa'=>array('1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'));
$arr = (array_map('count', $food));
//print_r($arr);
$c = 0;
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
  $c  += $v;    
}
echo $c;
```

**Max array count:**
Live demo :https://eval.in/87611

```
  echo max(array_map('count', $your2dArray));
```

It will return count of 2d array

If you want to get count of the all the elements then :

```
$array[0][0] = "one";
$array[0][1] = "two";

$array[1][0] = "three";
$array[1][1] = "four";
$c=0;
foreach($array as $a){

 $c =$c+count($a);
}
echo $c;
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/87617

Comment: @dear downvoter can i know the reason?

Comment: if it work you should accpet my answer :)

Comment: @Awlad_Liton is this work for 3d,4d ... arrays ?

Comment: -1 because max(array_map('count' ...) doesn't work. In your second examples it would return 2. Your "first" live demo only work because you have one line.

Comment: Chester: i have edited my answer for any dimensional array.  @mb14 : I have edited my answer

Comment: your 'max' is still wrong. You should use array_sum instead

Answer (score 1):

Just count each sub-array elements.

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $value)
{
     $count += count($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does work for 2d, 3d, 4d Arrays:

```
$myArray = array(array(1,2,3,4,5),  array(6,7), array(array(8,9)));
$countRec = count($myArray, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
print $countRec;
```

But this returns 13 as the result since it is counting: Elements in 1st Depth + Elements in 2nd depth ...

So it's calculation is: 2 + 8 + 1 + 2 = 13